# Determine the extrema of $\int^{x^2}_1\frac{\sin t}{2+e^t}\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine the local extrema of $F(x)=\int^{x^2}_1\frac{\sin t}{2+e^t}\,dt$. 
> Prove that $|F(x)|\leq|x-1|$ for all  $x$.

$$F'(x)=\frac{2x\sin x}{2+e^x}\mbox{,}$$
so that the set of all points at which $F$ may attains its local extremum are $n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know how to proceed any further.

Comment: Have you, firstly, worked out the derivative of this function with respect to $x$?

Comment: You should have some $x^2$ terms in your derivative.

Comment: $F(1) = 0$ and $F'(x) < 1$ for all $x.$  So $F(x) \le \int_1^x t \ dt$

Comment: I see the second problem follows from the mean value theorem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maybe more than one way to answer your question, however using the mean value theorem would be the most direct way to do it.

We have,
$$ |F'(x)|=\left|\dfrac{2x\sin(x^2)}{2+\exp(x^2)}\right|\leq\left|\dfrac{2x}{2+\exp(x^2)}\right|\leq\left| \dfrac{x}{1 + \frac{1}{2}\exp(x^2)}\right|\leq 1$$
The last inequality is valid for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, because then we have $2x\leq\exp(x^2)$

Given that $F(x)$ is continuous on $[1,x]$ and derivable on $]1,x[$, we can conclude using the MVT:
$$ \left|\dfrac{F(x) - F(1)}{x-1} \right|\leq 1$$
Finall, given that $F(1)=0$
we have $$ \left| F(x)\right| \leq \left| x-1 \right|, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

---

About the local extrema:
To find the local extrema of the function $F$, we need to solve the equation $F'(x)=0 $.

$$ F'(x)=0  \Longleftrightarrow \frac{2x\sin x^2}{2+\exp(x^2)}=0$$
Thus, $$ x= 0,\quad \mbox{or }\ \sin(x^2)=0 \Leftrightarrow x^2=n\pi,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

We can than conclude that the local extrema of the function are of the form $\pm \sqrt{n\pi}, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: How to determine the points at which $F$ attains it local maxima and minima?

Comment: $3x^2=0$ when $x=0$ but $0$ is not an extrema of $x^3$

Comment: Well, that's correct. However, that's not the case here, because the function $2x\sin(x^2)$ changes sign every time it crosses the $y=0$ line.